How to get the official release with the fix provided by RedHat support for Drools?
I have recently submitted a bug for Drools engine and received a fix as well but it is available in incubator projects. How can i get this fix in a official build to use?
Bug: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-7631
Fix Provided: https://github.com/apache/incubator-kie-drools/commit/d04ab13454f2bce80c4259e16584c6d71f425bf7

Hi @Prasanna Veeramani,
More than one year ago, the Drools project moved under the Apache organization and now is part of the Apache KIE product.
The fix you referred to will be part of the next Apache KIE release (most likely 10.1 version). If you need that fix immediately, you can rely on a temporary snapshot version released every week on the Apache repository. The latest version is 999-20240929-SNAPSHOT, which should contain the fix you need.

Thanks @Amer, Appreciate your response on this request.

Hey @Amer, do you have any idea about the timelines of 10.1 release?

Unfortunately, I don't, but if you need the lastest version to unblock your work, please use 999-20241016-SNAPSHOT version - you need to setup the apache repo in your pom.xml to download them
